# Probability with $2$ colored balls and one box: $1/3$ or $1/4$?

Tags: probability

We have $2$ balls in a box, each of them can be either black or white.

What is the probability that both balls are black?
$1\over 3$ or $1\over 4$?

---

$1\over 3$ because : 
we have $3$ nonrecurring cases:

1) white white (ww)

2) white black (wb)

3) black black (bb)

So, it's $1\over 3$

Comment: How are you eliminating a black white case from existing?

Comment: I don't know, people say that there is no difference between BW and WB, they mean that the order doesn't matter

Comment: In that case, are you sure all 3 cases have exactly the same probability of happening?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{4}$ as there are 4 cases: WW, WB, BW, BB where each is equally likely.

If necessary, consider adding extra balls and see if your theory would hold. If there were 4 balls, are there 16 cases or just 5? I see 16 as each ball could be either colour while you'd claim that order doesn't matter really.

4 color case where order doesn't matter: WWWW, WWWB, WWBB, WBBB, BBBB (This is your 5 case scenario.)

4 color cases where order matters:

WWWW

WWWB, WWBW, WBWW, BWWW

WWBB, WBWB, BWBW, WBBW, BWWB, BBWW

BBBW, BBWB, BWBB, WBBB

BBBB

Answer (score 1):

> Emil Terman
>
> > I don't know, people say that there is no difference between BW and WB, they mean that the order doesn't matter.

Yeah, this is a source of much confusion among new students.

When we say "order doesn't matter" what we actually mean is "some of these outcomes are indistinguishable except by order so we consider them to be the same event".   In this case, two balls are placed in a box where they roll around so that we can not tell which was placed in first.

> "When one ball is black and one is white, we can't tell which is first, so we say order doesn't matter."

What we *don't* mean by "order doesn't matter" is that these distinct events are a set of equally probable outcomes.   $\{\textsf{Both White}, \textsf{Both Black}, \textsf{Different coloured}\}$ is a set of three distinct outcomes, because "order doesn't matter", *but* these distinct outcomes are *not* equally probable.   That is important.

To measure probability as a **ratio** of counts of **distinct outcomes** (favoured versus total) we need all of the distinct outcomes to have be **equally probable** (ie: to have the same probability weighting).

We actually have the partitioned set: $\{\{WW\}, \{BB\}, \{BW, WB\}\}$.   This model helps us obtain a more meaningful measure of probability.

---

**too long/didn't read**: Sometimes "order doesn't matter" for identifying distinct events, but it still often *does* matter for weighing probabilities.